# Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() (with godaddy)

Tags: php, function, passwords, version, password-hash

I am having this error after I uploaded into the web server and realized that it might be the php version godaddy provides since I heard lots of these problems before.

Also, I ready the other post having this problem saying password_verify is a built in function as php5.5 and godaddy only provides up php5.2, 5.3 and 5.4

I am wondering if using php5.4 what can I do with the password_verify? Also, I am also using password_hash which is giving me errors too but I need to do both hash and verify through the database.

Comment: flee godaddy hosting while you can

Comment: If you read the [PHP docs for password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) you'll see reference to the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for earlier versions of PHP (>= version 5.3.7)

Comment: Dagon> I personally fleed godaddy and changed to hostgator haha but just the company I am working for loves staying with godaddy

Comment: Mark> ah, thanks I saw it so pretty much a Lib which will make password_hash and verify() work just the same like php5.5 as long as I include the library eh?

Comment: @aivfx - that's precisely it, include the library and it gives you exactly the same password_* functions as PHP 5.5

Comment: @Mark - thanks a lot, done it. Great so no other alternation needed. Way less code, thanks for the help :D I want to vote up for your name but somehow couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this library that someone created which appears to be exactly that (PHP 5.5 password functions for lower PHP versions)

https://github.com/Antnee/phpPasswordHashingLib

Comment: Why would anybody create a backport of PHP's password_* functions when the actual author of the core PHP password_* functions already [did it](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)?

Comment: No clue, didn't see that one, but either of them should work for what OP needs.

Comment: The main difference is that one is recommended for earlier versions of PHP

Comment: I didn't use this, and used the other one provided by Mark but since Mark only the message in comments so I couldn't use his and mark it as correct so I will mark yours as correct and resolved :D Thanks though. P.S. I didn't use yours because after all the one Mark gave is directly from php manual just that I didn't see that link. :D